# What are the energies (in eV) that we need to reach to create 'strings', gravitons and a 'Theory of Everything' (quantum gravity)?

Tags: energy, string-theory, dimensional-analysis, quantum-gravity, physical-constants

Somehow, I cannot find an answer on the Web....

Possibly because nobody knows, of course, but I would still like to find a 'ballpark' answer...

Creating the particles or whatever (and whatever they might be called... cannot find that on the Web either) that are associated with a 'Grand unified theory' (G.U.T.) merging the EM, weak and strong forces requires creating concentrated energies of a little over 10^24 electron volts, right?  Or a 'yottavolt'?

How many electron volts needed to create a string or graviton, approximately?

Comment: you did not specify which "string". If you mean strings from string theory, then any particle we see is a string, including graviton

Comment: So if you're using wireless to read this, the photons involved (which are strings, per string theory) have energies of around 1.6 yocto electron volts.  I was going to say if you were listening to AM radio it'd be something on the order of $10^{-28}\mathrm{eV}$, but there's no metric prefix for $10^{-30}$, which is a serious oversight.